# Applying shur's lemma to make triangular matirx

Tags: linear-algebra

$A=\begin{pmatrix} 2 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ has eigenvalue $\lambda=1$.
The eigenvector is (1, 1).
To make triangular matrix,
$U^{-1}AU=\begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}} \end{pmatrix}$ $\begin{pmatrix} 2 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ $\begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}} \end{pmatrix}$=$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}=T$

In here, I understand that the first column of $U$ is (1,1) because it's the eigenvector, and dividing it by $\sqrt{2}$ is to make it unit length.
But how can I derive the second column (1,-1)? I know it is orthogonal to column one, and also has unit vector by dividing  $\sqrt{2}$. Is there any formula I can use to calculate the second column? (Sine there is only one eigenvector, we have to make second column.)

Comment: In general, what you need are [generalized eigenvectors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_eigenvector), but in your particular case, actually any nonzero vector that is not parallel to $(1,1)^T$ can serve as the second column, so the second column does not need to be orthogonal to the first one.

Comment: @user1551 I suspect that thistime wants a Schur decomposition, so an orthogonal matrix is actually needed.

Comment: @Phira You're right, of course. I overlooked the "Schur" in the title.